# Rename terminal title && run application using alias

Tags: alias, gnome-terminal

Trying to create a command that rename terminal title and run a application, I'm adding the commands inside .bash_aliases file. The rename command I'm using is: `PS1='\[\e]0;test\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '`
If I use it alone and after run the application it works as expected. But if I use the command like this:

```
alias rpcs3="PS1='\[\e]0;test\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ ' && ./rpcs3/rpcs3-v0.0.25-14385-b639f3c8_linux64.AppImage"
```

Using this latter command, the terminal title only change after the application is closed as shown in the example below:

### Before closing the app

[image: before]

---

### After closing the app

[image: after]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias is not working because the shell prompt waits until your program finishes.

A solution to this is by first calling to your command `./rpcs3/rpcs3-v0.0.25-14385-b639f3c8_linux64.AppImage` and run it in background:

```bash
alias rpcs3="./rpcs3/rpcs3-v0.0.25-14385-b639f3c8_linux64.AppImage & PS1='\[\e]0;test\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '"
```

And given that your command will run in background when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> you will get back to shell prompt (the title will be set before, so this has no problem anymore). If you want to get back to foreground the process `./rpcs3/rpcs3-v0.0.25-14385-b639f3c8_linux64.AppImage` you should use the command: `fg`.
For getting which jobs are running in background in your current shell you can use the command/shell builtin `jobs`. For example:

```bash
$> jobs -l
#Output
[1]   Running                 gnome-calculator &
[2]-  Running                 gnome-calculator &
[3]+  Running                 nautilus &
```

If I want to get back to foreground the `nautilus` process I can use:

```bash
fg 3
#You can also specify the `command name` instead of the ID.
```

Probably in your case you only will have one process in background (`./rpcs3/rpcs3-v0.0.25-14385-b639f3c8_linux64.AppImage`). So you can simply use `fg 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use the prompt to change the title, which means the title will get changed only when your application exits. A better approach might be to change the title directly within your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
title='this is a test'
base='/PATH/TO/THE/ABSOLUTE/LOCATION/OF/rpcs3'    # Fixme

[ -n "$TERM" ] && printf "\033]0;%s\007" "$title"
exec "$base/rpcs3-v0.0.25-14385-b639f3c8_linux64.AppImage"
```

Put this script somewhere in your PATH (often `$HOME/bin` or even `/usr/local/bin`) and make it executable. You can then call it just like any other program. For example, if you've called the file `dorpcs3` then that's what you run.

Note that this does not reset the title after the application exits, but the default shell prompt will do that for you.